# Orientation change does not call onCreateView immediately after onAttach

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

I am having a parent `fragment`, and loading child `fragments` over it. So initially when I add `fragments` it follows proper life cycle events, like `onAttach(), onCreateView()` and so on. I am setting a member var in `onCreateView` and using it immediately after `commit()` from parent fragment.
But when orientation changes, onAttach() gets called and gets crashed while accessing member var, as it gets null. Seems like `onCreateView()` does not get called immediately.
Also tried `getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after `commit`, but did not work.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It seems that you are getting hung up on issues regarding orientation changes, but you seem focused on making sure the fragment transaction is completed. Posting the relevant parts of your code would help get this sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use in your manifest file 
use this in parent activity in which your fragment is

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

After that it will persist state upon rotate screen.
Hope it helps you. Test it and do let me know if this solves your issue.